# ASMX Webservice, Test Form only available on local machine for one WebMethod only

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have an ASMX WebService that I am testing, and on most of the methods I am able to use the test form just fine for testing. I do however have one method for which the test form says:

```
The test form is only available for requests from the local machine.
```

This method is declared exactly the same way the other methods, but it does have a noticeably longer parameter list (most of these methods only have 2 or 3 params):

```
[WebMethod]
    public ActionSuccessResponse makeDestinationRequest(String ownerID, String destinationRegion, String destinationCountry, DateTime desiredTravelDate1, String destinationCity = "", DateTime? desiredTravelDate2 = null, DateTime? desiredTravelDate3 = null) {
```

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Comment: try this http://geekswithblogs.net/juang/archive/2005/11/28/61437.aspx

Comment: That is already in my Web.config. There is only one method in my whole WebService which does not function properly through a browser.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how dumb the built in test page is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use the older ASMX files, you should test them with something like [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

The built-in test page only handles very basic parameter entry (and probably has a limit on the number of parameters before it gives up). Basically don't use it.

Comment: Great. Once you start with SOAPUI it is also easier for you to move to using web-hosted or windows-hosted WCF services instead of the much older and less rich ASMX services.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the problem was actually occurring due to the DateTime typed parameters in the method definition. Web Services should use primitive data types for all parameters to allow for compatibility with other languages.