# ASMX Webservice - The test form is only available for requests from the local machine

Tags: c#, json, web-services, asmx

I have an ASMX webservice with two functions. One sends a JSON object to the server and stores it in a file, while the other function retrives the JSON object from the server. The webservice works perfectly in local, but when I try it in a remote server, I get the well known "The test form is only available for requests from the local machine" error.

As suggested in different forums, I have added the protocols to my web.config file:

```
    <system.web>
        <webServices>
          <protocols>
            <add name="HttpSoap12"/>
            <add name="HttpSoap"/>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>       
          </protocols>
        </webServices>
   </system.web>
```

Adding the POST protocol makes the second function (the one that retrives the object) available from remote, but the first one is still only available from the local machine.

I haven't been hable to find the solution to this problem, as every solution I found was just to add the protocols in the web.config file, which only work for one of the two functions.

[There is one question which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037505/asmx-webservice-test-form-only-available-on-local-machine-for-one-webmethod-onl) seems to have a similar problem, caused by using DateTime type as input parameter. In my case, maybe it has something to do with using a "Object" type as imput for the function? What alternatives do I have if I can't use the Object type?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thank you and best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  VS 2012 did not publish the web.config to my published source after I added ws protocols.  It worked when I manually copied the file.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this can happen is that your parameters are more complex objects, including things like GUIDs