# Accepting null values in web service call

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I have the following method in my web service

```
<WebMethod(Description:="GetMerchants")> _
    Public Function GetMerchants(ByVal separator As String, ByVal DateFrom As String, ByVal DateTo As String, ByVal ID As String, ByVal MerchantID As String, ByVal RimNo As String, _
                                    ByVal Name As String, ByVal Description As String, ByVal Category As String,
                                    ByVal Region As String, ByVal isHidden As Boolean)
```

I want to send a null value to ishidden but it's giving me the following error

> System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert  to System.Boolean.
>   Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
>      at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
>      at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
>      at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

How can i set the default value of ishidden to false. 
By the way, It's not even entering the method. The error is shown when i click invoke and by putting the breakpoint i realized it's not even entering the method.

I searched in the web, i couldn't find a way to set a default value to an optional field. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: What values do you feed in then? What does your request look like?

Comment: You should also tag your question with the appropriate language to get appropriate help.

Comment: SELECT * from my_table where  (isHidden like '0' ), it works fine when i put ishidden as string but i want to put it as boolean just to test if i can set a default value for optional parameters

Comment: You should tag it with `VB` or `VB.NET` or whatever you are using as well. `Optional-parameters` is probably not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Since "bool" isn't nullable you would need to change it to a nullable type.

In C# I would write "bool? isHidden" instead of "bool", otherwise (which would be the same) is "Nullable isHidden".

So change the code to "As Boolean?" (a questionmark at the end). Then it should accept null. =)

The nullable type has two Properties, "HasValue" and "Value".

You can read about nullable types at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx

Comment: I tried it,I got the following message "The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters."

Comment: @Fares Joseph Eid - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037505/asmx-webservice-test-form-only-available-on-local-machine-for-one-webmethod-onl